# No route to host

Tags: networking, server, ssh

I'm creating an ubuntu server. I'm totally new.

The first redflag is when the pc is turning on, before everything is loaded, it fails in "a start job is running for wait for network to be configured".

At the beginning of the installation I set an Static ip for the server. Well, now when I do:

```
ssh -2C servidor@192.0.2
```

It responds with:

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.2 port 22: No route to host
```

where this ip is the static ip I set at the beginning.

ip addr

```
1: 10: LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000 
  link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
  inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  inet6::1/128 scope host
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp2s0: <NO-CARRIER, BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000 
  link/ether 70:5a:b6:d6:6f:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000 
  link/ether 78:e4:00:42:e9:0f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
  inet 192.168.0.120/24 metric 600 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic wlp3s0 
    valid_lft 5305sec preferred_lft 5305sec
  inet6 fe80::7ae4:ff:fe42:e90f/64 scope link
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip route

````
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.120 metric 600
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.120 metric 600 
192.168.0.1 dev wlp3s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.120 metric 600```

Thank you for all of you that would try help me
````

Comment: can you use regular IP address so we will known if its local or routed traffic. because you show  @192.0.2  witch is not well formatted.

Comment: then show us what is working, with ```ip addr```  and ```ip route```

Comment: Thank u! I edited the publication and I put that in it!

Comment: You set IP `192.168.0.120`, so that should be the address you need to SSH to.

Comment: May we see in an edit: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: "No route to host" with your "ip r" means that the destination is not connected to your network. Please run "ip n" and tell us if it contains the "192.168.0.2 dev wlp3s0 FAILED" problem.

Comment: "A start job is running for Wait for Network to be Configured" typically means one of your network interfaces (typically an Ethernet port) is configured to use DHCP, but can't get an IP address. Also for the commands you include, please make sure you only include information from the server. Mixing things up will only make it more confusing than it already is.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `ssh -2C servidor@192.0.2` isn't `192.168.0.2`, unless you've added `192.0.2` to your `~/.ssh/config` file, which I don't imagine you've done.  `192.0.2` expands to `192.168.0.2`, which isn't `192.168.0.2`.

So, first, you need to use proper hostnames or IP addresses when connecting via `ssh` (and pretty much everything else in the world).

If your network service is failing, why haven't you provided the errors here?  You should focus on getting your networking working first.

You seem to describe a single machine in your question, but you're trying to SSH to another machine?  It's unclear what interactions are intended here.

Comment: 192.0.2 is perfectly valid. It expands to 192.0.0.2 in both ssh and ping. Granted, it's not the 192.168.0.2 the asker wants.

Comment: It 'expands'?  What prevents it from 'expanding' to 192.69.0.2?  Very curious to look up additional information on this if you could please provide a name or mechanism for this.  Thank you!

Comment: Idk if it's specified. It's just what glibc does. Compile `#include<arpa/inet.h>
int main(){struct in_addr in;inet_aton("192.0.2", &in);puts(inet_ntoa(in));}` to see for yourself. I think "normalize" fits this more than my "expand". It also does octal stuff, which is a common source of security vulnerabilities, visible if you replace "2" with "020"